# Keep getting ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I have been working on fixing this problem for days. I keep getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in SatellitesController#create

Satellite(#70098878574220) expected, got String(#70098849353340)
```

I have looked all over this site but nothing seems to help. This is what I have in my code so far:

In my new.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for( @satellite ) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :parent_id %></br>
    <%= f.select( :parent_id, Satellite.all.collect { |s| [ s.name, s.id ] }, { :include_blank => '-select-' } ) %>
</div>
```

And this is the association I am using:

```
class Satellite < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

  has_many :satellites, class_name: 'Satellite', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent_id, class_name: 'Satellite', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Show the stacktrace of the actual error and the line of code it's referencing in your question.

Comment: Yes, specifically your `create` method in your `SatellitesController`.

Comment: def create
    @ satellite = Satellite.new(params[:satellite])

    if @ satellite.save
      redirect_to @satellite, notice: 'Satellite was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's related by why use select rather than collection_select?

```
<%= f.select( :parent_id, Satellite.all.collect { |s| [ s.name, s.id ] }, { :include_blank => '-select-' } ) %>
```

Could be

```
<%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Satellite.all, :id, :name, { :include_blank => true } %>
```

Also looks like the reference to your parent in the self referencing section of your model could be wrong.

```
belongs_to :parent_id, class_name: 'Satellite', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
```

I think this should be

```
belongs_to :satellites, class_name: 'Satellite', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
```

Comment: Nope that didnt help either. I still get the same Satellite(...) expected, got String(...).

Comment: When I change it to :parent I get the error invalid method :parent

Comment: Do I need to have a Parent class in the Satellite model where the association is?

Comment: Do you think you could put up your schema.rb section for Satellites?

Comment: ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130312022717) do

  create_table "satellites", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end

Comment: I've recreated your model locally and had a play around with it, I think if you change your belongs_to to match the latest edit above, it might work!

Comment: That got it! Thank you very much! =D